# Angular6 - Custom Input field

Tags: angular6

I have to create input field in Angular, that input field allow only number with 2 decimal places like `'123455.12'`

Below is what i have tried so far

```
<input myCustomDirective type="text">
```

I created Directive. In my CustomDirective I used HostListener for keypress event in that listener i used regular expression to validate but it allow only number it not allowing to enter '.(dot)'

`new RegExp('^[0-9]*$');`// my regular expression

Comment: AngularJS - Smart Float Directive , This is what are you looking for : https://gsferreira.com/archive/2015/02/angularjs-input-number-with-two-decimal-places/

Comment: i should enter only one '.' but your code i am able to enter more than one dot

Comment: Please check out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gsferreira/Lsv9f0b0/ , posted in link ,  ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" is the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here's a Directive that takes Only Decimal Values with custom
>   precisions.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-decimal-directive

- It will allow you to put digits before the .(dot)
- It will not allow you to paste (ctrl+v) non-decimal.
- It will take single .(dot) . by default it will take 2 digit after the . (dot).

**Example:**

```
`<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myVar" decimal>`
```

But you can define the precision size like that :-

```
`<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myVar" [decimal]="3">`
```

- If you want to use Only Integer not floating point you can use the Directive Like this:

  `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myVar" [decimal]="0">`
- If you don't complete enough precision in the input , then it will
  automatically complete rest of the number precision (also if a .(dot)
  needed) by onblur event.
- You Can't inject string value by two way binding.

**N.B: [(ngModel)] is mandatory for using the Directive.**

Comment: If I enterd 99.999 and i select entire text then enter "."  this scenario not working.

Comment: It will not work, because it will not take double dot(.) together .so if you want to replace whole text with the . (dot) first you have to erase the line with backspace after select entire text.

Comment: but we should not force the user. most of the user will select the entire text to override

Comment: Please check again [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-decimal-directive](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-decimal-directive)

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the fiddle [jsfiddle.net/gsferreira/Lsv9f0b0](http://jsfiddle.net/gsferreira/Lsv9f0b0) , posted in link , 
`ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"` is the key

From  Plain Old Java script fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/j3cbytws/

Only numbers please and a single dot allowed , nothing else:

```
<input type="number" name="someid" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" /> 

<script>
var isDecimalAlredyEcountered = false;
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if(isDecimalAlredyEcountered && charCode === 46)
    return false;
   if(charCode == 46)
    {isDecimalAlredyEcountered =true;
    }
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)&& charCode != 46)
        return false;
    return true;
}    
</script>
```

There can be an issue of backspace char and delete with the above implementation, so you have to reset the state on clear

Comment: thanks for your time. i should enter only one dot but your cases i am able to enter more than one dot

Answer (score 0):

ng-pattern that you reguire is `ng-pattern=" /^[.\d]+$/"`